# Genymotion action overflow icon

Tags: android, genymotion

This is probably an obvious setting that I can't seem to find but is there a way to get the Genymotion emulator to display the action overflow icon? It displays all my other action bar icons but it will never show the overflow and I don't see a hardware button anywhere that would take it's place. Thanks.

Comment: Which AVD configuration are you using?

Comment: Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 w/ Google Apps Api 17

Comment: when i launch an app, i get the overflow-button automatically at the lower right. also use the same avd like you.

Answer (score 3):

If the device has a menu button, the overflow button will be hidden.

You can force the device to show the overflow button with (in your Application onCreate method):

```
    // force the device to show the actionbar overflow button (4.0+ only...)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

On some Android devices, if a real menu button exists, the 3 dots ovorflow menu button will not be shown, and you must press the real menu button to display your menu.
These device usually don't have a navbar, but real physical buttons.

Genymotion takes that into account and for some device, hide the navbar. 
You then must use the Genymotion buttons on the right (Back/Home/Apps and Menu)

[image: Genymotion buttons]

Starting with Genymotion 1.1.0 you should be able to force the display of the NavBar (Back/Home/Apps) for all your devices from the settings of the Virtual device.

By activating it you'll force Android to display the 3 dots overflow menu on the actionBar of your app.

[image: Genymotion navbar setting]